# My facebook app renders blank for some users

Tags: html, facebook, heroku

I have built facebook app. It's hosted on:
http://resihop.herokuapp.com/.

The app is suppose to be visible here:
https://apps.facebook.com/393963983989013/

On facebook it's embedded in an iframe. The weird part is that for some users the content of the iframe is empty, just:

 and for some users it displays the page. Here is the html: that I got from inspect element:

Working:

```
<div>
    <noscript>&lt;div class="mas"&gt;&lt;div class="pam uiBoxRed"&gt;Du måste ha javascript aktiverat i din webbläsare för att använda Facebook-applikationer.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</noscript>
        <form action="https://resihop.herokuapp.com/?fb_source=search&amp;ref=ts" method="post" target="iframe_canvas_fb_https" id="canvas_iframe_post_4fe8ad942b9be6531902412" onsubmit="return Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)">
            <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="signed_request" value="x4b_ddxAkL71eQEdopzIZJpWZCmTPFqOMmmMvx_TCC8.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImV4cGlyZXMiOjEzNDA2NTQ0MDAsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM0MDY0ODg1Miwib2F1dGhfdG9rZW4iOiJBQUFGbVR1TlI2UlVCQU9zQkRkc2hwbkpNN0pKR0ZaQTNsaGhtMlViNWFlWkFpeFpDNnNYcWVEbXpaQjVqb1dtVUwzVTg1WW5wUWg2WkJVdUxQV3o2M1lIQk5aQVQ4a3dNNGNtWkExZU00MXZ5SU5KeVpDeWFpbDhWIiwidXNlciI6eyJjb3VudHJ5Ijoic2UiLCJsb2NhbGUiOiJzdl9TRSIsImFnZSI6eyJtaW4iOjIxfX0sInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxMDAwMDA2MjcwMTQzODQifQ">
        </form>
        <iframe class="smart_sizing_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="iframe_canvas" name="iframe_canvas_fb_https" src='javascript:""' height="800" style="height: 574px; "></iframe>
</div>
```

Broken:

```
<div>
    <noscript>&lt;div class="mas"&gt;&lt;div class="pam uiBoxRed"&gt;You need Javascript enabled in your browser to use Facebook Applications.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</noscript>
    <form action="https://resihop.herokuapp.com/" method="post" target="iframe_canvas_fb_https" id="canvas_iframe_post_4fe8adec0223e0f59580030" onsubmit="return Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)">
        <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="signed_request" value="yx5eMWJ-0WFSOHg5bkfxesurLc5zZcfuYdyuJqffv0M.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImV4cGlyZXMiOjEzNDA2NTQ0MDAsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM0MDY0ODk0MCwib2F1dGhfdG9rZW4iOiJBQUFGbVR1TlI2UlVCQUJ6NVRxdWRuaW1tN01ZVzRkdXhSMHczTU1zcDZvbU9ZZ3ZZVm1zZG11dVJLN1lEb1h6Mm9TYUFIeUpaQ2NsSjg5cFBFWkJaQ2haQURyMGZCWWIxOUxaQ0o0QnVaQnR3WkRaRCIsInVzZXIiOnsiY291bnRyeSI6InNlIiwibG9jYWxlIjoiZW5fVVMiLCJhZ2UiOnsibWluIjoyMX19LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNjUxNjY2NDgzIn0"></form>
    <iframe class="smart_sizing_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="iframe_canvas" name="iframe_canvas_fb_https" src='javascript:""' height="800" style="height: 294px; "></iframe>
</div>
```

One difference I have noticed is that the actions are different. I have waited for several hours now, so it might be a server-unsync-thing, but probably not.

Comment: added details, it's not the z-index. For some reason, for some users the facebook post doesn't seem to get any html back, or atleast not display it to the users.

Comment: Which users? which browsers? random?

Comment: all browsers. I've also tested to remove all content from the index-file apart from a <p>"Hello World"</p> in the body, it didn't matter.

Comment: all mayor (haven't tested with internet explorer) Seemingly random users.

Comment: It's only chrome and one user. This is the error:chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect